# How to make the bot ask a question after generating an answer from the FAQ file?

Tags: azure, chatbot, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I am making a bot to suggest the most suitable product according to what the user input. I have made an excel file with the product description as the question and the product name as the answer. I have used QnA Maker to read from the file and have asked the user a few questions with the Add QnA pair function. After the user has given a description of the product and receiving an answer from the bot, I want the bot to ask the user if he/she is satisfied with the product.

I am new to this service and will be grateful if someone could help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/multiturn-conversation

Comment: I cannot add a follow-up prompt for each and every possible answer. Is there any other way to do this? Like after the bot has generated an answer from the QnA, can it ask a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Azure Bot Composer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/introduction?tabs=v2x) and integrate your existing QnA Maker database with it. You can easily create Bot conversations with the user this way.

Composer is a visual bot programming tool where you can introduce the logic behind your bot app. It uses the Bot Framework SDK from Microsoft and generates code that you can later refine. Within Bot Composer you can integrate services such as LUIS and the QnAMaker Knowledgebase that you already have. Of course, you can always use the Bot Framework SDK and start programming your Bot app from scratch with code.

To connect your existing QnAMaker Knowledgebase with Bot Composer: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-add-qna-to-bot?tabs=v2x)

First steps tutorial with Bot Composer: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/tutorial/tutorial-introduction)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am really confused with all the services. Could you please tell me in details how should I proceed? I have already fed the QnA maker with my data, tested and published it. What should I do next? Thank you.

Comment: Hi NShini, I´ve answered you in the previous response. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Hello, after feeding the QnA Maker with the data, I created a bot and downloaded the source code and an emulator for testing. The problem is I want the bot to ask a question after giving the user the product name (with help of the QnA maker). How can the bot ask a question without receiving an utterance? Thank you in advance.